# Crear campo de solo lectura en formulario html que inhabilite copiar, pegar y escribir

Tags: html

Necesito un campo (field) que va a mostrar contenido no se pueda escribir ni copiar ni pegar de ninguna manera.

Comment: Hola Kevin, como qué "necesito un campo" ? Has intentado algo? has buscado en google?

Comment: Si tu meta es que el usuario no pueda copiar ni pegar de ninguna manera el valor del campo, por qué usar un campo? Manipularlo es tan sencillo como visualizar el código fuente o usar el inspector de elementos, y listo. En su lugar, plantéate [generar una imagen con el valor que quieres representar, usando para ello por ejemplo, php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636984/using-php-gd-to-create-image-form-text-with-different-fonts).

Answer (score 4):

Si lo que quieres es tener un `input`, entonces intenta así:

- El atributo `readonly`, permite evitar que el usuario pueda modificar su valor.
- Si al evento `onmousedown`, le configuramos un `return false`, evitaremos que se pueda seleccionar el contenido y por ende no se podrá copiar.

Ejemplo:

```html
<input type="text" value="Texto" readonly onmousedown="return false;" />
```

### Update

Para evitar que se puede seleccionar el contenido del `input` iniciando la selección desde fuera, es necesario deshabilitar la selección de todo el `document`

Ejemplo:

```js
// Deshabilitamos la seleccion
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
// BONUS - Deshabilitamos el menu contextual
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
Texto fuera y antes del campo <br/>
<input type="text" value="Texto" readonly /><br/>
Texto fuera y despues del campo
```

Comment: solo como nota: Si se selecciona fuera del `input`, haciendo 3 clic con el mouse fuera del `input` o haciendo `Ctrl + A` se selecciona y puedes copearlo

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:
Permite dar estilo a in DIV para que se parezca a un input tipo text, por lo que no se puede modificar, sin embargo lo de copiar el contenido no está resuelto.

**CSS3**

```
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="input">Tu contenido aquí</div>
```

Comment: Todavía puedo copiarlo..

Comment: Puedes usar el atributo disabled en el input. <input type="text" name="mmm" value="tu contenido" disabled />

Comment: Todavía. Habrá alguna manera de crear una imágen en vez de un input? Por ejemplo, el usuario en el formulario del enlace que desea acortar http://ejemplo.com, que se cree una imagen de un tamaño de un input sin fondo?

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, si bien el input que agregué se puede seleccionar, este no puede ser copiado y además está desabilitado, así, se evita que copien o cambien su contenido.

Saludos.

```html
<input type="text" disabled value="Soy un texto" oncopy="return false;"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Desde html en la parte del body, hay atributos que pueden ser usados para estos casos: oncopy, oncut y onpaste, que por default vienen como true (verdadero), por lo que habría que darles valor de false ( falso ) por ejemplo:

```
<body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">
<input type="text" name="hola" readonly="true" value="test" />
</body>
```

Saludos

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar tu respuesta?, como tal usuarios futuros podrían no entender tu respuesta, es decir para que se usa el `oncopy` es atributo especificados en `xhtml` o `html 5`, solo por agregar mejor valor a tu respuesta

Comment: Como tal, este código impediría copiar o cortar (además de pegar) contenido en cualquier campo de cualquier formulario en la página. Se podría desarrollar un poco más para que verifique que el campo es el deseado.